# Why identityStoreHandler is null?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jakarta-ee-security-api

This is my **JWTAuthenticationMechanism** :

```
package xxx;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.AuthenticationStatus;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.HttpAuthenticationMechanism;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.HttpMessageContext;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.RememberMe;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.credential.Credential;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStoreHandler;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.Pbkdf2PasswordHash;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static ir.vinapacs.configuration.security.jwt.Constants.*;

@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition(
        dataSourceLookup = "${'java:jboss/datasources/MyDBJNDIDB'}",
        callerQuery = "#{'select user_pss from EntityUser where user_login = ?'}",
        groupsQuery = "select group_name from caller_groups where caller_name = ?",
        hashAlgorithm = Pbkdf2PasswordHash.class,
        priorityExpression = "#{100}",
        hashAlgorithmParameters = {
                "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Iterations=1000",
                "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Algorithm=PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512",
                "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.SaltSizeBytes=32",
                "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.KeySizeBytes=32"
        }
)

@RememberMe(
        cookieMaxAgeSeconds = REMEMBERME_VALIDITY_SECONDS,
        isRememberMeExpression = "self.isRememberMe(httpMessageContext)"
)

@ApplicationScoped
public class JWTAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    /**
     * Access to the
     * IdentityStore(AuthenticationIdentityStore,AuthorizationIdentityStore) is
     * abstracted by the IdentityStoreHandler to allow for multiple identity
     * stores to logically act as a single IdentityStore
     */
    @Inject
    private IdentityStoreHandler identityStoreHandler;

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Override
    public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpMessageContext context) {

        LOGGER.info(request.getRequestURI());
        // Get the (caller) name and password from the request
        // NOTE: This is for the smallest possible example only. In practice
        // putting the password in a request query parameter is highly insecure
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("login : " + name + "::" + password);
        String token = extractToken(context);

        if (name != null && password != null) {
            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(name + ":" + password));

            // validation of the credential using the identity store
            CredentialValidationResult result = identityStoreHandler.validate(new UsernamePasswordCredential(name, password));

            System.out.println("result:" + result);
            if (result.getStatus() == CredentialValidationResult.Status.VALID) {
                // Communicate the details of the authenticated user to the container and return SUCCESS.
                return createToken(result, context);
            }
            // if the authentication failed, we return the unauthorized status in the http response
            return context.responseUnauthorized();
        } else if (token != null) {
            // validation of the jwt credential
            return validateToken(token, context);
        } else if (context.isProtected()) {
            // A protected resource is a resource for which a constraint has been defined.
            // if there are no credentials and the resource is protected, we response with unauthorized status
            return context.responseUnauthorized();
        }
        // there are no credentials AND the resource is not protected,
        // SO Instructs the container to "do nothing"
        return context.doNothing();
    }

    /**
     * To validate the JWT token e.g Signature check, JWT claims
     * check(expiration) etc
     *
     * @param token   The JWT access tokens
     * @param context
     * @return the AuthenticationStatus to notify the container
     */
    private AuthenticationStatus validateToken(String token, HttpMessageContext context) {
        try {
            if (tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                JWTCredential credential = tokenProvider.getCredential(token);
                return context.notifyContainerAboutLogin(credential.getPrincipal(), credential.getAuthorities());
            }
            // if token invalid, response with unauthorized status
            return context.responseUnauthorized();
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException eje) {
//            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Security exception for user {0} - {1}", new String[]{eje.getClaims().getSubject(), eje.getMessage()});
            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf("Security exception for user " + eje.getClaims().getSubject() + " - " + eje.getMessage()));
            return context.responseUnauthorized();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the JWT using CredentialValidationResult received from
     * IdentityStoreHandler
     *
     * @param result  the result from validation of UsernamePasswordCredential
     * @param context
     * @return the AuthenticationStatus to notify the container
     */
    private AuthenticationStatus createToken(CredentialValidationResult result, HttpMessageContext context) {
        if (!isRememberMe(context)) {
            String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(result.getCallerPrincipal().getName(), result.getCallerGroups(), false);
            context.getResponse().setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, BEARER + jwt);
        }
        return context.notifyContainerAboutLogin(result.getCallerPrincipal(), result.getCallerGroups());
    }

    /**
     * To extract the JWT from Authorization HTTP header
     *
     * @param context
     * @return The JWT access tokens
     */
    private String extractToken(HttpMessageContext context) {
        String authorizationHeader = context.getRequest().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith(BEARER)) {
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring(BEARER.length(), authorizationHeader.length());
            return token;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * this function invoked using RememberMe.isRememberMeExpression EL
     * expression
     *
     * @param context
     * @return The remember me flag
     */
    public Boolean isRememberMe(HttpMessageContext context) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(context.getRequest().getParameter("rememberme"));
    }

}
```

And :

```
package xxxx;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.credential.Credential;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.credential.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult;
import jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult.INVALID_RESULT;
import static jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.CredentialValidationResult.NOT_VALIDATED_RESULT;
import static jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore.ValidationType.VALIDATE;
import static java.util.Collections.singleton;

@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticationIdentityStore implements IdentityStore {

    private Map<String, String> callerToPassword;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        callerToPassword = new HashMap<>();
        callerToPassword.put("payara", "fish");
        callerToPassword.put("duke", "secret");
    }

    @Override
    public CredentialValidationResult validate(Credential credential) {
        CredentialValidationResult result;

        if (credential instanceof UsernamePasswordCredential) {
            UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePassword = (UsernamePasswordCredential) credential;
            String expectedPW = callerToPassword.get(usernamePassword.getCaller());
            if (expectedPW != null && expectedPW.equals(usernamePassword.getPasswordAsString())) {
                result = new CredentialValidationResult(usernamePassword.getCaller());
            } else {
                result = INVALID_RESULT;
            }
        } else {
            result = NOT_VALIDATED_RESULT;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ValidationType> validationTypes() {
        return singleton(VALIDATE);
    }
    /*@Override
    public int priority() {
        return 100;
    }*/
}
```

my pom is :

```
<!-- Jakarta EE 10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaEE.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mvc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaMVC.version}</version>
            <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

after deploy i get this exception:

ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /VinaServer/api/j_security_check: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStoreHandler.validate(jakarta.security.enterprise.credential.Credential)" because "this.identityStoreHandler" is null

Why this exception is thrown?